# Extract the divergent/bounded part of a certain expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Consider I have a power series which is function of $x$. A part of this expression is bounded when $x->\infty$, some remainder is on the other hand divergent when $x$ goes to infinity. 
What is the simplest way to extract out of my expression only the bounded part?

Comment: I believe you're talking about a power Series. Otherwise you can always manipulate any expression to have as many "divergent" parts as you want cancelling out themselves when you add them up

Comment: Sure, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: One place to start might be `Series[func, {x,Infinity,1}]`. If the divergent part is of polynomial or similar growth this might capture it.